# Issue with custom workflow action(SandBox)

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow-activity

I've created a custom workflow action using the VS2010 for SharePoint 2010 online. But whenever I use the custom action within a workflow and attach it to a list, it never runs successfully. While debuging, I always get the following error: "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to re-enable function evaluation." in the following code snippet:

```
SPSite oSite=new SPSite(context.CurrentWebUrl);
```

where context is the 'SPUserCodeWorkflowContext'. 'context.CurrentWebUrl' always return the current site url. But the 'SPSite' object does not work.

Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a little bit because of the lack of more of your code but are you performing something like the following?

```
try
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(context.CurrentWebUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
etc..
```

"The code gets the context to the current Site using the workflow context, and then opens the current Web and creates a site within it with the specified name."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/office365trainingcourse_lab_3_2_topic3.aspx

Comment: You probably already found this but this is related to your error message.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234762.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bob for your valuable reply. I'm still struggling with this issue though.